# Change the TextBlock Text present in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate in which I have a Grid layout with 2 RowDefinitions. I have a TextBox in the first row and a ComboBox in the second row.

I have defined the DataTemplate in my ResourceDictionary.

This is the code for the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name ="txtChannelDescription" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbChannelTag" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am using this DataTemplate in code behind as:

(DataTemplate)FindResource("myDataTemplate")

How do I set the Value of TextBox.Text and the ItemSource of the ComboBox at runtime?
I am using the DataTemplate as template for DataGridTemplateColumn.Header.

Comment: You should *bind* both properties to some properties of a ViewModel class. Search the Web for MVVM, and read the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom data type that suits your purpose (with properties named `ChannelDescription` and `ChannelTag` in this example) and then bind the values to your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type NamespacePrefix:YourDataType}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ChannelDescription}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelTag}" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" 
            Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

It would be used like this:

In your view model, you would have a collection property, lets say called `Items`:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Items { get; set; }
```

(Your property should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface unlike this one)

In your view, you would have a collection control, lets say a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}" />
```

Then each item in the collection control will have the same `DataTemplate`, but the values would come from the instances of type `YourDataType` in the `Items` collection.

Comment: If I use the template for more than once then the TextBox and ComboBox will have same content everywhere right?

Comment: @Sheridan If I am not wrong It will be DataType instead of TargetType.

Comment: @ethicallogics That's right, and even setting `DataType` is not generally necessary, unless you want the DataTemplate to be applied automatically. That doesn't seem to be the intention of the OP.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll update the example to say `DataType`. @Abhishek, the idea is that you would have one of these data types for each instance of your `DataTemplate`, so no they wouldn't all have the same value... I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Ok, but the `DataType` on the `DataTemplate` in your example is still redundant, as the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` is set explicitly. IMO the answer would be better without it, as it may only create confusion.

Comment: Hey @Clemens, with all due respect, I prefer to declare types, for example, using `TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}"` instead of `TargetType="ListBox"`... are you going to complain about that too or am I allowed to choose the way that I write my own code without you giving me pointless comments? Tell me something, what is the harm of using this `DataType` declaration? That's right, there is no harm... it's perfectly legal and therefore *can't* cause any confusion. Please keep your comments about your coding style preferences to yourself... I prefer to write code the way that I write code.

Comment: Hi @Sheridan. Your answer was helpful. But the DataTemplate Controls are not showing the bound values where as when I bind the same to another control like TextBox, its showing the value.
I am actually using the DataTemplate as a ColumnHeader for a DataGrid, which has a TextBox and a ComboBox.

Comment: It might have been nice if you had mentioned that earlier... unfortunately I have no experience of binding in the `DataGrid.ColumnHeader`. Fortunately, if you search online for the words  'binding in DataGrid.ColumnHeader' you will find several complete solutions, many on this site.

Comment: @Sheridan I'm in no way complaining about anything, just trying to improve this answer. As you might know, StackOverflow is a collaborative question and answer site, and people are encouraged to improve other people's posts to increase the overall quality of the content of this site. In that sense, it is not "your code" alone as soon as you have posted it here. And of course I won't "keep my comments on your coding style preference to myself" as long as I have the feeling that there is something to improve. My opinion: keep it simple. Don't set DataType when it's not necessary

Comment: Here we go again... @Clemens, you really haven't suggested any improvement here. Setting the `DataType` property is optional in this instance. Not setting it is not an improvement... it's optional. I chose to include because it made it clear that the `DataTemplate` was for the `YourDataType` class in my example.

Comment: How can you set the `DataContext` of what?

Comment: @Sheridan:
I followed your suggestion and looked it up. I found that  `<TextBox Name="txtChannelDescription" Text="{Binding DataContext.ChannelDescription, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
<ComboBox Name ="cmbChannelTags" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ChannelTags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>` is the answer.  Now I have one more issue. The ChannelDescription and ChannelTags are properties defined in a Class. How can I set the DataContext multiple times?

Comment: @Sheridan: The `DataContext` for the `TextBox` Text and the `ComboBox` ItemSource. I have them defined as properties in a Class. And I am creating an object for the Class and setting it as the `DataContext` in the constructor.

Comment: You seem to have become confused again. You don't set the `DataContext` multiple times... we set the `DataContext` of the view (or UI) to be the view model class, not the data type class. The data type class is in a collection (called `Items` in my example) which is in the view model. The idea is that the view model class holds *all* of the data that we want to show in the UI. The data is accessed through the `Items` property. You can set the `DataContext` in a `DataTemplate` in `App.xaml`: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:YourViewModel}"><Views:YourView /></DataTemplate>`

Comment: I just noticed your code example in your comment (not the best place for code)... you don't want to set the `DataContext` on the `DataGrid` otherwise nothing else in you view will have access to data from the view model. Set the `DataContext` of the view (`Window`/`UserControl`) to an instance of your view model class (that contains *all* of the data your view needs). Then in your view, use a binding like this: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}" />`.

Comment: I think I should ask under a new question now that my question here is answered